# Show Gutenberg facebook embed with a custom theme

Tags: php, block-editor, facebook, embed

I'm working on a custom theme, and I would like to display the facebook embed from Gutenberg in Wordpress.  I've done `parse_blocks` and then printing the block displays just the facebook url.

```
// page-home.php
$post = get_post();
if (has_blocks($post->post_content)) {
  $blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);
  foreach($blocks as $block){
    if ($block[blockName] === 'core/embed/facebook') {
      // starting to get stuck here...
    }
  }
}
```

How do I display the facebook embed?

Comment: To output the content of the editor, including embed blocks, you should only need to use `the_content();`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just tried it, but I don't think that does what I want.  I'm seeing that all contents of the page prints, and the embed is just a facebook url in text.  I'm losing hope, I don't think that it's gonna work.